# SQL Server 2016: select * from sys.objects returns different result when run from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'MySP'
```

When ran in a query window it gives the needed result. But when I run it in a stored procedure, it returns nothing.

Here is the code in the stored procedure:

```
declare @ProcName nvarchar(255) = 'MySP'    

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = @ProcName)
        THROW 51000, N'NOT_IMPLEMENTED',1;
```

The 'MySP' procedure is new, do I need to refresh cache or something? What am I missing here?

The `IF` statement throws the error e.g. it does not find any results, which there should be. I even tried to use just the exact same select as in my query window and it does not return results.

Comment: You are just selecting inside the `IF NOT EXISTS` statement. Like this you aren't returning anything. You'll need an `ELSE` block to return results.

Comment: You are using NOT EXISTS here, that means if the SP 'MySP' is exists in the database then there will be no action , other wise it will produce the error as u mentioned in the script.

Comment: It does work with all my other procedures I am using. Just this new one is causing issues.

Comment: @Abdul Rasheed I understand that. Maybe my question was not so clear. The IF statement THROWs the error e.g. it does not find any results, which there should be. I even tried to use just the exact same select as in my query window and it does not return results.

Comment: Are you sure your query window is pointing at the right database? Are you running under the same user account both times?

Comment: @Martin Smith Yes. I have just one DB and just one User, so I can't mess it up.

Comment: @MartinSmith You were right. In the main calling procedure there was a WITH EXECUTE AS 'WebExec' statement which needs 'WebExec' permission to be granted manually to the new Stored Procedure. Please Answer my question so I can accept it as Answered. Thank you!